# How to activate my specific parent menu link after clicking it a second time

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure if there is a better way I should be going about this, but I have a situation where I have to click a parent menu navigation link to show the dropdown child links for that parent link, THEN the parent link will become available to click on to go to a specific page. When I click outside of the parent link and it's child link options, the dropdown menu closes again.  So all of that is great.

Here is what I have so far...

```
var mtargetmenusection = $('#menu-top > ul > li');

mtargetmenusection.one('click', function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();
var mthis = $(this);
if(mthis.find('div[class^="dropdown"]').length != 0) {
mthis.find('div[class^="dropdown"]').stop(true,true).css({display:'none'}).slideDown(150);
}       
});

$(document).click(function(e){
$(".dropdown").fadeOut(50);
});
```

So based on this code, if I had already clicked on a parent link from my menu navigation, and then click on a second parent link off the menu navigation, how can that click tell the previous parent link I clicked on first, to not be an active link and instead default to only opening up it's own dropdown menu?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Kevin. Your code inspired me to take a deeper look in how my problem can be solved.  With the code below, I am taking the following approaches:

1. First cancelling the default CSS hover effects with jQuery
2. Then using the on method to detect if a dropdown menu is displayed or not, which then determines how preventDefault is used.
3. Finally hiding all dropdown menus if you click anywhere in the document.

[You can see my demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/blackhawx/ez3Xu/9/).  And here is the code below:

The HTML:

```
<div id="menu-top" class="jq-off">
<ul>
<li>
<a href="http://www.google.com"><span>About</span></a> 
<div class="dropdown">
<ul>
<li><a href="/">one</a></li>
<li><a href="/">two</a></li>
<li><a href="/">three</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>

<li>
<a href="http://yahoo.com"><span>Join</span></a>
<div class="dropdown">
<ul>
<li><a href="/">one</a></li>
<li><a href="/">two</a></li>
<li><a href="/">three</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#menu-top {
    background:#f1f1f1;
    text-align:center;
    opacity:0.9;
}

#menu-top > ul {
    padding:0; 
    margin:0 auto;
    display:table;
}

/*FIRST LEVEL*/

#menu-top > ul > li {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    list-style:none; 
}

#menu-top > ul > li:hover > a, #menu-top > ul:not( :hover ) > li.active > a, #menu-top ul li a:hover {
  color:#444;
}

#menu-top > ul > li > a {
    margin:0;
    padding:0 13px; 
    display:block;
    line-height:400%;
    font-size: 100%;
  color:#001489;
  text-decoration:none; 
    outline-color:#f1f1f1;
}

#menu-top > ul > li span:after {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 0.39em solid transparent;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top-color: #fff;
    border-top: 0.39em solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0.39em solid transparent; 
    border-left-color: #444;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    right: -0.353em;
    top:-0.1em;
}

#menu-top > ul > li:hover span:after {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 0.39em solid transparent;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top-color: #444;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    right: -0.353em;
    top:-0.1em;
}

#menu-top .trans {
    display:none;
}

/*SECOND LEVEL*/
#menu-top.jq-off > ul > li:hover > .dropdown {
    display:block;
}

#menu-top .dropdown {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
  white-space: nowrap;
    background: #f1f1f1;
}

#menu-top .dropdown ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style: none;
}

#menu-top .dropdown ul li a {
  padding:0;
  margin:5px 10px;
  display:block;
  color:#444;
  font-size:90%;
    line-height:250%;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  text-decoration:none;
    text-align:left;
}

#menu-top .dropdown ul li a:hover {
    color:#444;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

/*CHROME-SAFARI ONLY*/
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 

  #menu-top > ul > li span:after, #menu-top > ul > li:hover span:after {
    border:none;
    }

    #menu-top .trans {
    position:relative;
    left:5px;
    display:inline-block;
    transition-property:transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s; 
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    }

    #menu-top > ul > li:hover .trans {
    transform:rotate(deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    }
}
```

The jQuery:

```
function menu() {
//disable the default css hover action
$('#menu-top').removeClass('jq-off');

$('#menu-top > ul > li').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var mthis = $(this);    
    var mparentdropdown = mthis.find('.dropdown');

    //prevent default link action for this parent link if this dropdown is hidden
    if (mparentdropdown.is(':hidden')) { 
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }

    //if a dropdown is hidden on click, then hide all other dropdowns and slide down this dropdown
    if(mparentdropdown.css("display") == "none"){
        $(".dropdown").fadeOut(50);
        mparentdropdown.stop(true,true).css({display:'none'}).slideDown(150, function(){ });     
    }
});

//click anywhere in the document to close all dropdown menus
$(document).click(function(e){
    $(".dropdown").fadeOut(50);
});
}

(function($) {
menu();
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're over-complicating it. you don't need .one, and you don't need to know if the element exists to slidetoggle it.

```
var mtargetmenusection = $('#menu-top > ul > li');

mtargetmenusection.on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var mthis = $(this);
    mthis.find('div[class^="dropdown"]').stop(true, true).slideToggle(150);
});

$(document).click(function (e) {
    $target = $(e.target);
    if ($target.is("#menu-top > ul > li")) {
        // only hide siblings of the clicked li
        $target.siblings().children(".dropdown").fadeOut(50);
    } else {
        // hide them all
        $(".dropdown").fadeOut(50);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V68Fm/1/

The difference is clicking on an li only interacts with that one li, and then doesn't stop the event from bubbling. Then, when the event reaches the document, the document handles hiding the other non-related dropdowns, or all if the clicked element wasn't one of the lis.